# iOS: SearchBar don't display cursor text

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

I have a strange problem with my `SearchBar`, it don't show the `cursor text` but I can input the text.
Here is the code that I use to initial `SearchBar` then add it to `NavigationBar`

```
self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] init];
self.searchBar.placeholder = @"Search";
self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
self.searchBar.delegate = self;
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchBar;
```

Did I make something wrong?

[image]

**UPDATE**

Change the tint color of `SearchBar` fix my problem with `cursor text`. The `cursor text` will show with black color

```
self.searchBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

**However**, the problem is the `Cancel` button will change the color to black too
[image]

Comment: Are you using clear color for the tint?

Comment: Here is all attribute that I use for my search bar

Comment: Thank @Desdenova, I fix it by change the tintColor for my SeachBar to black. However, I still dont know why the default color of my SearchBar is transparent :(